# How do I format the numerical labels in a legend?

Tags: stata

In Stata, the following code produces a contour plot:

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway (contour headroom mpg price), legend(on)
```

The plot looks as follows:

[image]

How do I change the legend to automatically format its labels as `1.0`, `2.0` etc.?

I would like to do this without having to manually create labels and pass them to the `legend` option.

In my actual application, I'm trying to get this to work for a map that comes from the `spmap` command, but it's difficult to provide a minimal working example with that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to re-format the numbering in the `clegend` of the contour plot (as opposed to the 'traditional' `legend`).

In this case, you just need to specify the `zlabel` option and the required format:

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway contour headroom mpg price, zlabel(#5, format(%2.1f))
```

This will produce the desired output:

[image]